# Как инициализировать массив данными из файла?

Tags: matlab

Имеется текстовый файл data.txt, в котором записаны 8-битные числа в шестнадцатеричном формате:

```
11
ab
af
be
```

как инициализировать этими данными массив? Я знаю, что вначале мне нужно
`fp = fopen('C:\users\user\desktop\data.txt','r');`, а затем, `fscanf(fp..)` но вот как правильно оформить форматную строку и что сделать дальше не пойму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел:

```
fp = fopen('C:\users\user\desktop\data.txt','r');
a = fscanf(fp,'%x')
```

Проблема была в том, что я пытался вызвать функцию наподобие си-шной, т.е:
`fscanf(fp,'%x',a)`